# Why don't we completely de-couple frontend JS frameworks and backend APIs?

Tags: design-patterns, web-development, architecture, programming-practices, angularjs

Whenever we implement a frontend framework in the likes of Backbone, AngularJS etc. there's an integration process involved with the backend technologies like NodeJS, Rails, Yii etc. (like setting up routes, generating views or adding libs etc.) which varies depending upon what you select at the front-end and what you take at the backend, my question is:

Why don't we completely de-couple the process so that front-end (HTML, CSS, JS etc.) is completely independent while backend APIs returns us desired data only, just like we do in mobile development.

Comment: How would the frontend know where to put the data that it receives from the backend API without some sort of annotations or mapping mechanism?  In other words, how do you propose to decouple?  Without more detail, I don't see how your question is answerable.

Comment: By saying complete de-coupling, I've probably made wrong sense of isolation, let me try to re-phrase:

- In mobile apps (like iOS & Android etc.) we develop frontend using native technologies while for the data we use backend APIs i.e. it doesn't care if our API is written in Ruby or Python. Why don't we use same process in usual routine and de-couple or web front-ends in the same way.

Comment: Because if you write it natively, you have to do it again for each device type you have to support (Android, iOS, Windows PC, etc.), but if you write in in HTML/CSS/JS, you only write it once, and run it in a browser available on every device.

Comment: Thanks for the help Robert, after a little research, I got the answer (you may check it below and comment further if you like). But I'm still unsure why it's not a standard practice to use front-end frameworks in such a way.

Comment: I am not sure why you wouldn't do it, but I do it all the time :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an architectural choice and you don't need any particular kind of framework to accomplish it, whether on front- or back-end.

One way to accomplish it (and this is supported by at least some single app javascript frameworks) is to write your front-end with no knowledge or connections to the backend beyond a set of URLs that supply or accept whatever data you require.

Really, your own answer is correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

Alright I've found what I was looking for, the simplest answer to my question is that we could do this sort of de-coupling and depending upon what and why we need it, something like **Hoodie framework** (http://hood.ie/) already implements what I had been thinking about, but I presume it's not just that, we can use this sort of implementation in pretty much any given front-end framework.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "decoupling."

Comment: May be I am not using the right term in simple words, I was asking about keeping my backend framework and frontend one separate, so lets say if I ever have to change from rails to django I may not even need to rewrite a single line of frontend code to shift my backend. i.e. treating backend framework as 100% api only server.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Initially, think of HTML+CSS+JS that (aside from initial load) only communicates with the server by way of REST APIs and JSON, using something like Mustache.js to render the HTML client-side.  This Hoodie framework seems to be taking it further, though.